# traversal tree NLP python. How to use DFS method to look for VP subtree to find the verb that is deepest in the subtree

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, nlp, tree-traversal

I am new to the NLP traversal. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JBVS.png)

for example the sentence: Scroll bar does not work the best either.
I would like to use  DFS method to look for VP subtree to find the verb that is deepest in the subtree. Could you please help me get these verb? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use the stanford cornlp to get the triples